# Adding Sidebars in WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, sidebar

I'm trying to add two new sidebars on my WordPress website [here](http://www.sushidelivery.com.ph), one on the left and the other on the right, the main content then will be in the middle. Making the layout a three column.

I am using a **Ready! To be** Theme with **Ready! E-Commerce plugin**, I have also made the child where I made most of the changes.

The problem is the sidebar is not appearing on the website itself.  And when viewing the Widgets area under Appearance Menu the widget area I added does not appear even after registering it.

This is the code I inserted on the **front-page.php**:

```
<?php get_sidebar('left'); ?> 
<?php get_sidebar('right'); ?>
```

I then proceeded to create two sidebar.php files namely

**sidebar-left.php** which has the following code

```
<?php
/**
 * The Sidebar containing the main widget areas.
 *
 * @package Ready_ecommerce
 * @since Ready_ecommerce 0.1
 */
?>
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area sidebar" role="complementary">
        <?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>
        <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-6' ) ) : ?>
                <aside id="search" class="widget widget_search">
                        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </aside>
                <aside id="archives" class="widget">
                        <h1 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Archives', 'ready_ecommerce' ); ?></h1>
                        <ul>
                                <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly' ) ); ?>
                        </ul>
                </aside>
                <aside id="meta" class="widget">
                        <h1 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Meta', 'ready_ecommerce' ); ?></h1>
                        <ul>
                                <?php wp_register(); ?>
                                <aside><?php wp_loginout(); ?></aside>
                                <?php wp_meta(); ?>
                        </ul>
                </aside>
        <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
</div><!-- #secondary .widget-area -->
<style type="text/css">
    #content {
        float: left;

    }
</style>
```

**sidebar-right.php** with the code:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Sidebar containing the main widget areas.
 *
 * @package Ready_ecommerce
 * @since Ready_ecommerce 0.1
 */
?>
<div id="secondary-2" class="widget-area sidebar" role="complementary">
        <?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>
        <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-5' ) ) : ?>
                <aside id="search" class="widget widget_search">
                        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </aside>
                <aside id="archives" class="widget">
                        <h1 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Archives', 'ready_ecommerce' ); ?></h1>
                        <ul>
                                <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly' ) ); ?>
                        </ul>
                </aside>
                <aside id="meta" class="widget">
                        <h1 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Meta', 'ready_ecommerce' ); ?></h1>
                        <ul>
                                <?php wp_register(); ?>
                                <aside><?php wp_loginout(); ?></aside>
                                <?php wp_meta(); ?>
                        </ul>
                </aside>
        <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
</div><!-- #secondary .widget-area -->
<style type="text/css">
    #content {
        float: right;
        width: 759px;
    }
</style>
```

And last, added the following lines to **functions.php**

```
register_sidebar( array(
            'name' => __( 'Content Pages Right', 'ready_ecommerce' ),
            'id' => 'sidebar-5',
            'description' => __( 'Right sidebar area for content pages only. Not availabe at products or catalogue pages', 'ready_ecommerce' ),
            'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => "</aside>",
            'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title' => '</h2>',
        ) );
    register_sidebar( array(
            'name' => __( 'Content Pages Left', 'ready_ecommerce' ),
            'id' => 'sidebar-6',
            'description' => __( 'Left sidebar area for content pages only. Not availabe at products or catalogue pages', 'ready_ecommerce' ),
            'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => "</aside>",
            'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title' => '</h2>',
        ) );
```

Comment: I think that your theme probably has a side bar. Email the theme's author and ask them how to enable it before you customize it.

Comment: @stink Well when I first viewed their front-page.php , the _<?php get_sidebar(); ?>_ was initially commented out, so I just assumed that is how the make use of sidebars, unfortunately there was still no response from the theme's author.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php if(function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-6')) : ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area sidebar" role="complementary">
<?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>
<?php if(function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-6')) : ?>
<aside id="search" class="widget widget_search">
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
</aside>
<aside id="archives" class="widget">
    <h1 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Archives', 'ready_ecommerce' ); ?></h1>
    <ul>
        <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly' ) ); ?>
    </ul>
</aside>
<aside id="meta" class="widget">
    <h1 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Meta', 'ready_ecommerce' ); ?></h1>
    <ul>
        <?php wp_register(); ?>
        <aside><?php wp_loginout(); ?></aside>
        <?php wp_meta(); ?>
    </ul>
</aside>
<?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
```

#content {float: left;}

Please try the above code in sidebar-left.php and check from Appearance > Widgets . Drag the text widget into sidebar and write some demo text and check. Let me know your update.

Comment: Still nothing the only widget area there is Content Pages Right, the Content Pages Left does not appear.